# Postgres 9.5 cache lookup failed

Tags: postgresql-9.5, pg-trgm

I am trying to install pg_trgm into postgres (Using postgres 9.5 on ubuntu 16) by doing `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm`. The first executable line of pg_trgm--1.1.sql is

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_limit(float4)
RETURNS float4
AS 'MODULEPATH_NAME'
LANGUAGE C STRICT VOLATILE;
```

Running this line in psql or starting psql with `psql -f pg_trgm--1.1.sql` throws error `ERROR:  cache lookup failed for function 1`. Any idea why this might be happening. I also tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION add(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
AS 'select $1 + $2;'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

which works fine. Do I have to install something to create sql functions using C language? I already installed contrib for postgres using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib`